# Adding remote function to model in Loopback.js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have added a remote function in loopback.js model, which works fine, when i add another function with different name & url then new function works but previous one starts giving error 500.

I have tried with changing name of function i am calling, changing api url and all these things but it didn't worked

First function was this

```
Station.remoteMethod(
    '_updateStation', {
        http: { path: '/update', verb: 'post' },
        accepts: [
            { arg: 'service', type: 'object', required: true, http: { source: 'body' } },
            {
                arg: 'ip', type: 'string', required: true, http: function (ctx) {
                    var req = ctx.req;
                    return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||  req.connection.remoteAddress;
                }
            }
        ],
        returns: [
            { arg: 'status', type: 'string', description: ' stations update status' },
            { arg: 'statusCode', type: 'string', description: ' stations update code' }  
        ]
    }
);
```

And new function is

```
Station.remoteMethod(
    '_updateMultiple', {
        http: { path: '/updateall', verb: 'post' },
        accepts: [
            { arg: 'service', type: 'object', required: true, http: { source: 'body' } },
            {
                arg: 'ip', type: 'string', required: true, http: function (ctx) {
                    var req = ctx.req;
                    return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||  req.connection.remoteAddress;
                }
            }
        ],
        returns: [
            { arg: 'status', type: 'string', description: ' stations all update status' },
            { arg: 'updateData', type: 'string', description: ' stations all update code' },
            { arg: 'stations', type: 'string', description: ' stations all update code' }    
        ]
    }
);
```

> If i comment out the new function, the /update api works fine, but if uncomment this new function, then /update api gives error 500

Comment: What's the message for the error 500. Do you have any output on your terminal?

Comment: I got the issue, issue is with /update api if i change it to any other name like /updates then all things work fine,  as /update is also the built in api exposed for model in loopback js, i think which is doing something & causing error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this query, it was simple. Just disable that function of model which you want to override and then add function, it will work. For example
If you want to add custom /update api on model, you need to do.

```
    _Model.disableRemoteMethodByName('update', false);
```

And then add new remote method with /update url, it will work.
Because if you don't disable model remote function, and create /update, it will still give call to model built in /update method, instead of your custom /update method.